# Can I temporarily connect a dishwasher with hoses running along the floor?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I currently live in an in-laws suite with my wife in the in-laws house.  We love it and have plenty of room.  Look at the attached picture for what we have for a space.  My question is if I wanted to add a dishwasher.  I'm looking at getting a cheap scratch and dent Bosch at a store foreclosure this weekend. Can it be set up about 6 feet from the sink and the water lines be ran along the floor possibly as this will not be a permanent setup and can not be too destructive as there is no plumbing where I have space for the dishwasher.  In the picture I want to put the washer next to the fridge in the corner.

[image]

Comment: Are you considering tying the water and drain lines into the plumbing below the sink or hooking them up as needed in the front?

Comment: Under the sink if possible.  I was thinking since this is a temp setup until we move out and would most likely take the dishwasher with us, I would just lay the tubing on the floor (concrete)and put one of those hard wire covers over the walking area and then drill holes in the side of the cabinet to get over to the drain and water line. Not pretty by an means, but if it makes it so I don't have to redo the plumbing in the walls that's great.

Comment: What are you doing about power requirements? Builtin dishwashers are often installed on a dedicated hardwired circuit.

Comment: Can they be ran off a 110v 20 amp circuit?  If so could I setup the dishwasher to use the same plug as the fridge by wiring the cables to a 3 prong wall outlet.  The only other device on the circuit would be the fridge.

Comment: Water gets mad when you try to make it go up hill, and usually throws a temper tantrum all over the floor.

Comment: Why not just get the dishwasher, and store it until you can install it properly.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of issues with the plan.

The biggest problem may be the routing of the water supply and drain across the door threshold. Wire covers are intended to cover wire, not hollow tubing. More importantly, the channels in them are usually not more than 3/4 high (most smaller) and will not fit a drain line. If you could find one large enough, it would pose a trip hazard at the doorway.

The next issue is the risk of damage to the tubing under the wire cover. You would need to ensure that the cover was rigid enough and stable enough to avoid both compression of the lines and tugging on the fittings (although you could put full or partial loops in the lines to avoid strain).

Dishwasher drain lines are usually fairly short, and the run you propose may be more than the dishwasher pump can handle. The hot water line is under pressure, so that would not be a problem, but I would consider using PEX to avoid crimping issues.

If you do this, you will still need to put in a branch on the drain and a branch with a shutoff valve on the water supply.

You may want to consider a [portable dishwasher](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Portable-Dishwasher-in-White-with-12-Place-Settings-Capacity-GSC3500DWW/203248875#.UjB0NcaKIuc) such as this type

[image: portable dishwasher]

Smaller ones are also available in countertop versions. They are wheeled to the sink for use, and attach to the faucet and drain over the lip of the sink. They can easily be taken with you and most can be converted to a built in when you are ready.

Comment: The reason I am trying to figure this out is i'm getting a very good deal on a scratch and dent dishwasher.  Its a Bosch from a foreclosed furniture store new in the shipping boxes for $100. Only issue is a leg is slightly bent. I could find something sturdy to go over the tubing.  Like I also said its a very temp solution this is just a make shift kitchen. I was just concerned the drain line wouldn't work.

Comment: It may or may not. You should try to get the Bosch specs to see if they indicate a waste line length limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just put dishwasher next to sink and move a cabinet over next to fridge.

You will have put a counter on the dishwasher anyway.  It is a lot easier to cut out cabinet and hook up dishwasher next to sink and then take said cabinet or another cabinet and put in next to fridge and slap count on top of it.  If your dishwasher is all by itself next to the fridge you will have to buy a dishwasher cabinet (expensive for really no reason other than they know the people that need them are stuck).

You are asking a question that is very hard to answer because you haven't considered an easier solution (even if it doesn't seem easy to you at first).

Also if you read the dishwasher manual you can probably use the same power for your garbage disposal and still be code.  I just had this exact situation in my house 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to run that much drainage line as the dishwasher will always have water in the pump and possibly the bottom of the basin.  Pulling out the nearest cabinet to the sink would be best as previously stated.   Otherwise I'd invest in some dishwashing gloves.    Don.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider placing your dishwasher just next to the sink, even for the price of blocking the left sink. After all, you won't use sinks that much once you get a dishwasher. Running the water and drain pipes through the doorway is the critical point. I wouldn't dare myself having them on the ground.

For water, this is solvable in your proposed position, water is usually well pressurized to make it into tall buildings, so it should make it above the door frame. But the drain pipe cannot be placed above the door since it's hardly complaint with the dishwasher's specifications, and very likely it wouldn't work. However, there is the shower and the closet nearby, so depending on how much "damage" you can do in the place, you could seek for ways how to connect the drain pipe there.